# Kivy page layout cover one page over the other to prevent overlapping

Tags: android, python, kivy, page-layout

In Kivy, I am trying to cover the first page over the other after I pull the second page over the first page. At the moment there is overlapping of the words from the list because the pages seem transparent and the second page does not cover the first one. I tried changing the background color of the widget but to no avail, even tried adding a background image at some stage. Please help this has taken up enough of my time. I would appreciate a solution in pure python instead of kv language if possible. Example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.pagelayout import PageLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle

# Window.clearcolor = (252, 235, 233, 0)

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class PageLayoutScreen(Screen):
    pass

class PageLayout1(PageLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PageLayout1, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        myList = ['hello there', 'hello to you too']
        t = 0
        for i in myList:
            nameWdgt = Label(text="[b]" + myList[t] + "[/b]", markup=True, font_size='15sp')
            locationWdgt = Label(text="[b]" + myList[t] + "[/b]", markup=True, font_size='15sp')
            self.add_widget(nameWdgt)
            self.add_widget(locationWdgt)

            # below is my attempt to cover the first item in the list "hello there" when we pull the second item in the list over it "hello to you too"
            with self.canvas.before:
                Color(0, 1, 0, 1)  # green; colors range from 0-1 instead of 0-255
                self.profile_layout = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)
            t += 1

root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
#:import sys sys
MyScreenManager:
    transition: NoTransition()

    PageLayoutScreen:

<PageLayoutScreen>:
    name: 'test'
    PageLayout1
''')

class ScreenManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget

ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Label` is by default transparent other than the texture (text) that's why you are seeing the overlap. Your attempt to create a background merely drew a rectangle with it's default sizing. You need to draw a background for each label to see what's going on.

edit: I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish using `ScreenManger` and `Screen` so I left them out.

Here's an example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.pagelayout import PageLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

Builder.load_string("""
<MyLabel>:
    font_size: "15sp"
    markup: True
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.bg
            rgba: [[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1], [.5, .5, .5, 1]][self.pg_index]
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

""")


class MyLabel(Label):
    pg_index = NumericProperty(None)


class PageLayout1(PageLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PageLayout1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        myList = ['hello there', 'hello to you too']
        pg_index = 0
        for i in myList:
            nameWdgt = MyLabel(text="[b]" + myList[0] + "[/b]", pg_index=pg_index)
            pg_index += 1

            locationWdgt = MyLabel(text="[b]" + myList[1] + "[/b]", pg_index=pg_index)

            pg_index += 1

            self.add_widget(nameWdgt)
            self.add_widget(locationWdgt)


class ScreenManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PageLayout1()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks @Mox your solution works, but i found a piece i was missing by using just python with layout.canvas.add(Color(0., 1., 0)) and layout.canvas.add(Rectangle(size=(100, 100))). They work best when inside a ScrollView in case someone has an issue when looping over them